# How to find the electric flux by a point charge place at an edge of an infinitely long triangular prism?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I know that the solution will require for us to either a)Use symmetry and somehow create a closed gaussian surface and then apply gauss' law or b)use geometry to find the portion of charge which can be considered wholly inside the prism

Comment: Is the charge placed on the inside or outside of the prism?  Are you looking for enclosed flux?  Are you looking for electric flux or magnetic flux?

Comment: The charged is placed on the edge of the prism, neither inside nor outside. Yes I am looking for enclosed electric flux

Answer (score 0):

i will show how to solve considering the base of prism to be equilateral triangle and its at the vertex.

imagine the point charge to be at one of the vertex of base of the prism.

you can add six more prism in exact same way like the point charge is at the end of the prism.(such a way that it looks like regular hexagon base prism with point charge at center. connect all vertex of hexagon to the center to visualize the 6 prism).

you can similarly add another 6 prism down to make it look like hexagon beam.
now since the point charge is completely covered by gaussian surfaces the flux passing through is q/e(e is epsilon).and also the flux passing through all the equilateral triangle base prism are same as they are symmetrical.

there 12 such prism so (q/e)/12 = q/12e.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. I'm sorry for not mentioning, but i did mean triangular prism. Did we add 6 prisms because 360/60=6? i.e. we will need 6 60° angles to make a full structure?

Comment: ya thats right.